# integrating an odd function on the whole complex plane.

Tags: complex-analysis

let $f$ be an odd function ($f(-z)+f(z)=0$ for any $z\in \mathbb{C}$ ), and $C_r$ is a circle centered at the origin with radius $r$, is it true that : $$\lim_{r\to \infty} \int_{C_r} f(z) \ \mathrm{d}z = 0 .$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is false in general.  If $f$ is entire, then sure.  On the other hand you haven't put any restriction on $f$ other than it being odd.

Let $z = e^{it}$, then $dz = iz\ dt$.  $\int_{-\pi R}^{\pi R} f(e^{it}) e^{it} i dt$.  Now  $f(e^{it}) e^{it}$ is $\pi$ periodic by the oddness of $f$ and so for $R = n \pi$, we see that this is just
$$2n \int_{0}^{\pi} f(e^{it}) e^{it} i dt$$

$f$ can now be chosen somewhat arbitrarily as we are only defining it liberally on the upper half plane.

Also if $f$ is even, the integral is $0$ too.

Comment: thank you, does it hold if $f(z) = \frac{\cot(\pi z) }{z^2+1}$ ? I'm trying to find the integral of $f$ on the whole complex plane.

Comment: Ah, that is a different story altogether.  Use the residue theorem.  $\cot(\pi z)$ has simple poles on $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\frac{1}{z^2 + 1}$ has poles at $z = \pm i$.  It's a good idea to always ask your original problem too so people can see what motivated the question.

Comment: yes I know, I'm trying to calculate this integral in order to calculate an infinite sum $\sum (n^2+1)^{-1}$, can you tell me if the integral of $f$ (the function that I mentioned in the first comment) on the whole complex plane equals zero or not ?(just yes or no) ?

Comment: Oh right, The best way to do that is by looking at orders of magnitude.  Take $R = n + \frac{1}{2} $ and see what happens to $\cot(\pi R e^{i t})$.  But yes, the integral will go to zero.

Comment: Thank you so much, I got it now.